# Unable to reference an object in a variable within colnames

Tags: r

I am unable to reference the object contained in the variable "Symb" within the colnames function. For example:

```
symb <- "IBM"

colnames(paste0(symb)) <- c("Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adjusted")
```

Comment: Um... duh? How could a string have column names?

Comment: @SeñorO - It could if you do `t(vector)` :) Or use `NROW` and `NCOL`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to name the columns of a data frame called IBM, and the variable symb is a character vector that contains the string "IBM". If so, then you might try

```
df <- get(symb)
colnames(df) <- c("Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adjusted")
assign(symb, df)
```